# In Ruby, Python, or PHP, is there a insertion to the middle of the Array object thats take O(1) time?

Tags: php, python, ruby, arrays, performance

I think typically, insertion to the middle (any where) of an array can be costly -- it can take O(n) time to shift the elements over one slot, and possibly reallocation of memory for the array.  On the other hand, a linked link can take O(1) time.

But in Ruby, Python, and PHP, is there an array object that only takes O(1) time to insert an element in the middle of the array?

**update: And it has to follow that the replacement of the array element any where in the array or accessing it is also O(1).**

**update: insertion as in the following:**

```
1.9.3-p125 :001 > RUBY_DESCRIPTION
 => "ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]" 

1.9.3-p125 :002 > a = %w{ a b c d }
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 

1.9.3-p125 :007 > a.insert(3, 123)
 => ["a", "b", "c", 123, "d"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by middle here, do you mean anywhere that isn't either end, or `len(array)/2`?

Comment: The python dict() implementation has average runtime of O(1): see http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Furthermore your question is very specific, if you provide some context, we could help you solve your actual Problem.

Comment: @sleeplessnerd And is unordered, so the concept of a 'middle' doesn't really apply.

Comment: sorry, yeah, middle meaning any where in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you have `\SplDoublyLinkedList` that can do this for you. http://php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php

Note that PHP arrays are not arrays that you see in C, C#, Java, etc - they are ordered hash maps. See the intro of http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Depending on your use case (if this isn't homework), `\SplMaxHeap` isn't O(1) but may be your optimal choice. http://php.net/manual/en/class.splmaxheap.php

Comment: @hakre How does one insert into the middle of a doubly linked list without knowing what item is in the middle?

Comment: @Lattyware: As stated in the question, the middle is already known. It's where insertion takes place. If you doubt, ask the TS for clarification. (oh you did, the example of middle you give is okay, even the exact middle is okay for middle.)

Comment: The question is worded like ones often found on an academic test, where 'middle' only means not the start or end. Hence, in this context, where middle exactly lies isn't as important as the O complexity of inserts.

Comment: @hakre: I don't see it stated that the middle is known.

Comment: @Lattyware: I see you don't see it, but the TS is not asking about insertion of an element at an unknown location. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @hakre I may not have been clear - what I mean is wherever you wish to insert in the middle of the list, you will need to get to the point you wish to insert it to add it in. A doubly linked list will still require you to traverse the list to get to the insertion point, which is an O(n) operation.

Comment: yes, the assumption is that you know the location -- about insertion,  usually the location of the insertion is already known.  The O(1) being concerned is just the insertion, not finding where to insert

Comment: I see, sorry, this is my lack of understanding. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @JeremyL When discussing data structures, "insertion" means traversing to the point of insertion, if necessary, as well as actually performing the insertion.  You may be asking about a special case where for some reason you already have a pointer to the insertion point, but you should specify this if so - that is not and should not be the assumption in general.

Answer (score 0):

Given the discussion, it may be that in Python a [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-objects) fits your description. It's a double-ended queue, which [appears to be implemented as a doubly linked list](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bc6d28e726d8/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this in Ruby with the builtin methods.

Comment: @skrafi: There is a builtin method to do it, but it is not `O(1)`.